# Currency values string split by comma

Tags: java, split

I have a String which contains formatted currency values like `45,890.00` and multiple values seperated by comma like `45,890.00,12,345.00,23,765.34,56,908.50` ..

I want to extract and process all the currency values, but could not figure out the correct regular expression for this, This is what I have tried

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currencyValues = "45,890.00,12,345.00,23,765.34,56,908.50";
    String regEx = "\\.[0-9]{2}[,]";
    String[] results = currencyValues.split(regEx);
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
    for(String res : results) {
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

The output of this is:

```
45,890 //removing the decimals as the reg ex is exclusive
12,345
23,765
56,908.50
```

Could someone please help me with this one?

Comment: You mean you want to have the `.00` back ? The input values should use a better delimiter instead of using comma, which is quite confusing.

Comment: Yes.. I want the decimals back in the output, I don't have control over the input string, It is beeing fed from external application.

Comment: If it's not homework maybe it makes more sense so use `String.split` for the commas, and `SimpleDecimalFormat` to parse the values. With that you can control it's really a number, the decimal separator format, and then format that decimal value the way you want.

Comment: @helios: Using `String.split` with commas would be difficult as the commas are used both as field separator and decimal separator.

Comment: @beny23: Ouch! You're right :) I didn't pay enough attention to detail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need a regex "look behind" `(?<=regex)`, which matches, but does consume:

```
String regEx = "(?<=\\.[0-9]{2}),";
```

Here's your test case now working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String currencyValues = "45,890.00,12,345.00,23,765.34,56,908.50";
    String regEx = "(?<=\\.[0-9]{2}),"; // Using the regex with the look-behind
    String[] results = currencyValues.split(regEx);
    for (String res : results) {
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
45,890.00
12,345.00
23,765.34
56,908.50
```

Comment: Great! It works, missed the "look behind". Will accept the answer in a moment. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You could also use a different regular expression to match the pattern that you're searching for (then it doesn't really matter what the separator is):

```
 String currencyValues = "45,890.00,12,345.00,23,765.34,56,908.50,55.00,345,432.00";
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,3},)?\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{2}");
 Matcher m = pattern.matcher(currencyValues);
 while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
 }
```

prints

```
45,890.00
12,345.00
23,765.34
56,908.50
55.00
345,432.00
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `\\d` matches a digit
- `\\d{1,3}` matches 1-3 digits
- `(\\d{1,3},)?` optionally matches 1-3 digits followed by a comma.
- `\\.` matches a dot
- `\\d{2}` matches 2 digits.

However, I would also say that having comma as a separator is probably not the best design and would probably lead to confusion.

EDIT:

As @tobias_k points out: `\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*\\.\\d{2}` would be a better regex, as it would correctly match:

- 1,000,000,000.00

and it won't incorrectly match:

- 1,00.00

Comment: Just wanted to post the same answer, but with a different regex, i.e. `"\\d{1,3}(,\\d{3})*\\.\\d{2}"`. Yours will fail to match values such as "d,ddd,ddd.dd", but will match things like "dd,dd.dd"

Answer (score 0):

In all of the above solutions, it takes care if all values in the string are decimal values with a comma. What if the currency value string looks like this:

String str = "1,123.67aed,34,234.000usd,1234euro";

Here not all values are decimals. There should be a way to decide if the currency is in decimal or integer.

Comment: try improving your answer with more details. Try quoting a little bit from the question so is clear to which aspect are you answering. Like "in all of the above solutions". Also, you are debating between decimals and integer and your example contains not digit chars. You probably want to refer to formatted number according to a schema.

Comment: (This could potentially a new question or comment to an existing answer.) If your string always have currency codes at the end of the values and you want to preserve them in the output, you could use something like `(?<=[0-9][a-z]{3,4}),`. All we are doing here is, try finding at least one digit, 3 to 4 characters and comma to split.

Comment: Thanks for replying to me. The answer that I want in above string (String str = "1,123.67aed,34,234.000usd,1234euro";) is just the numbers without the currency abbreviation.

Comment: @ZenabGorach Then you don't need the look behind. All you need is `[0-9][a-z]{3,4},`.